# Put 2 columns in single row horizontal recycleview for all screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I have one parent `Horizontal Recycleview` which contains twelve `Vertical Recycleviews`. I would like to show only two columns per page, on only one horizontal row. I use `GridLayoutManager`.

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
            layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```

Increasing span to **`2`** it creates two rows which i don't want.

Also i tried `layout:width` in xml to fixed value in `dp` or `sp` that results in different number of columns on different screen sizes.

**xml** for each block

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/view_table_view_game_block_constraint_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_round_top"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_table_view_odds_block_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_table_view_odds_block_hometeam"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_table_view_odds_block_time" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_table_view_odds_block_drawable"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_table_view_odds_block_hometeam" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_table_view_game_odds_awayteam"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_table_view_odds_block_drawable" />
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: did you try adding attribute orientation = horizontal to recyclerview?

Comment: yes i have added horizontal attribute to recycleview, still same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set width dynamically according to the screen size. this is the best way to get perfect result.

Update onBindViewHolder of your Horizontal Recyclerview like that.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersAdapter.UsersAdapterVh holder, int position) {

        UserModel userModel = userModelList.get(position);

        String username = userModel.getUserName();
        String prefix = userModel.getUserName().substring(0,1);

        holder.tvUsername.setText(username);
        holder.tvPrefix.setText(prefix);
        holder.item_layout.getLayoutParams().width = getScreenWidth(context)/2;
    }

 public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
        WindowManager wm= (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        return dm.widthPixels;
    }
```

This is how the RecyclerView item layout looks like for the given example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/holder_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/users_bg"
            android:layout_height="50dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prefix"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/headerColor"
                android:text="T"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/headerColor"
            android:text="username"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```